# titan- elasticseach and com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex

Tags: elasticsearch, titan

I am a newbie with titan.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and using cassandra 2.0 and ES 1.0 installed from deb packages.

I am trying to get ES to work with titan.

```
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('/var/titan-cassandra-0.4.2/conf/titan-cassandra.properties') 
Could not find implementation class: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex

storage.index.search.backend=elasticsearch
storage.index.search.hostname=127.0.0.1
storage.index.search.cluster-name=elasticsearch
storage.index.search.index-name=titan
storage.index.search.client-only=true
storage.index.search.sniff=false
storage.index.search.local-mode=false
```

So..does titan work wit ES?

update...

I am now using the server version for 4.2  titan-server-0.4.2.zip.  Now I get the below.

```
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('/var/titan-server-0.4.2/conf/titan-server.properties')
WARN  org.elasticsearch.transport.netty  - [Key] Message not fully read (response) for [0] handler org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SniffNodesSampler$1$1@1f6d83b9, error [true], resetting
Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
Display stack trace? [yN] WARN  org.elasticsearch.transport.netty  - [Key] Message not fully read (response) for [1] handler org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SniffNodesSampler$1$1@2e37735d, error [true], resetting
WARN  org.elasticsearch.transport.netty  - [Key] Message not fully read (response) for [2] handler org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SniffNodesSampler$1$1@62c436b7, error [true], resetting
WARN  org.elasticsearch.transport.netty  - [Key] Message not fully read (response) for [3] handler org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SniffNodesSampler$1$1@21cccaf3, error [true], resetting
WARN  org.elasticsearch.transport.netty  - [Key] Message not fully read (response) for [4] handler org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SniffNodesSampler$1$1@597b112, error [true], resetting
WARN  org.elasticsearch.transport.netty  - [Key] Message not fully read (response) for [5] handler org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SniffNodesSampler$1$1@76088b4b, error [true], resetting
WARN  org.elasticsearch.transport.netty  - [Key] Message not fully read (response) for [6] handler org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SniffNodesSampler$1$1@547da7dd, error [true], resetting
```

Comment: And people, make sure you invoke the gremlin shell as `root` user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ElasticSearch 0.90.5, which is corresponding to the version that is used by Titan 0.4.2.

Cassandra 2.0 is okay although Titan 0.4.2 packages with 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry we couldn't get to your issue in a more timely fashion.  As suggested on the mailing list this morning, you likely have a dependency problem as that error is indicative of `titan-es-x.y.z.jar` not being around.  What version of Titan did you download? Note the feature matrix:

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads#wiki-feature-matrix

You won't have ES packaged unless you download Titan Server or Titan All.  We hope to improve packaging in Titan 0.5 to make things easier.

Comment: titan-cassandra-0.4.2.zip is the version I installed

Comment: so I have to download titan-all-0.4.2.zip?  even though I dont want es and cassandra embbedded?

Comment: Well, if you don't have the `titan-es*.jar` (and its related dependencies) then you will get the error you are seeing, so either download one of the packages i suggested as described in the feature matrix or try to figure out the right combination of jars to include in your classpath to get `titan-es*.jar` working

Comment: It woudl be helpful if the version compatibility cheat sheet or release notes were boldly called out near the downloads feature matrix. https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Version-Compatibility

Comment: added a link just below the matrix: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads